# What written notation is used in IPA for the letter "A" in the English words "hand", "man", "and", et cetra?

Tags: phonology, ipa, phonemes, phonotactics, phonetic-symbols

In American English, the letter "***A***" is pronounced at least five different ways.

What written symbol in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (IPA) is used for the vowel, or vowel group, shown in the leftmost column of the table below?

That is, what written symbol is used for the sound produced by Americans who speak the following works aloud:

> *and*, *man*, *hand*, *ran*, *sand*

---

| Examples of Words Which Use Vowel One *AH* | Examples of Words Which Use Vowel Two *AW* | Examples of Words Which Use Vowel Three *UH* | Examples of words Which Use Vowel Four *EH-EE* | Examples of words Which Use Vowel Five *EH* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A**nd | s**A**w | **A**meric**A** | **A**ge (EH-EE-J) | **A**ny (EH-N-EE) |
| **A**pple | p**A**rt | **A**bility | **A**ble (EH-EE-B-UH-L) | **E**conomic |
| **A**sk | r**A**w | **U**mbrell**A** | p**A**ge (P-EH-EE-J) | **E**dge |
| **A**nswer | cl**AW** | **A**gain | s**A**ge (S-EH-EE-J) | **E**ducation |
| h**A**nd | p**AW** | **A**go | eng**A**ge | **E**ffect |
| m**A**n | str**AW** | **A**head (UH-H-EH-D) | **E**ffort | **E**lection (EH-L-EH-K-SH-UN) |
| c**A**n | L**AW** | **A**lone | _ | **E**lse (EH-UL-SS) |
| r**A**n | gn**AW** | **A**pply | _ | **E**nd (EH-N-D) |
| s**A**nd | _ | **A**bout (UH-B-AH-OO-T) | _ | _ |
| **A**fter | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| **A**ct | _ | _ | _ | _ |

Comment: Sorry, but this can be trivially found with a little research. The site rules say we don't answer "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for", and this is pretty simple to find an answer to. For example, have you looked in an English dictionary that has IPA on its entries?

Comment: In addition to @jogloran’s point (which is 100% true – you can easily find the answer on Wiktionary, for instance), there are several mistakes in your table. Firstly, the vowel in _part_ is different from all the ones in _-aw_ for those who don’t have the _cot–caught_ merger. Secondly, the first e in _election_ is /ə/, not /ε/, the e in _effort_ is /ε/, not /eɪ/, and the e in _economic_ is more commonly /iː/. Thirdly, _effort_ and the entire last column except _any_ don’t contain the letter a at all, so they’re not even examples of what the table is supposed to show.

Comment: @jogloran Someone who is very new to linguistics may not know how to go about finding that answer. Not everyone knows that English dictionaries with IPA symbols exist. I had never seen a dictionary with IPA before I got to grad school. Kind and helpful answers are more useful than dismissive replies.

Comment: Laura, we have to set the bar somewhere. Otherwise, the site's going to devolve into poorly-researched questions of no interest to anyone. I think "look up a dictionary" is a pretty low bar to set.

Answer (score 4):

The IPA symbol for the vowel sound that you are asking about is /æ/. What might be helpful to know is that there are a couple of websites that are useful for finding/typing these symbols, and that is how I quickly copied the character to paste it here, in order to answer your question! One is https://ipa.typeit.org/ and another is https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/ipa.htm

Comment: For a simple /æ/, you probably don’t need to go to some website at all. At least on a Mac, you can write _æ_ on a standard US keyboard just by hitting `Opt` + `'`.

Comment: Good to know for Mac users, I don't have a Mac, so I always have to copy-paste, or do "insert symbol" in Word.

Comment: Huh, it seems you’re right – the standard US keyboard layout on Windows doesn’t let the user type _any_ diacritics at all (and the UK one only a few). You have to switch to the US/UK International layout to be able to properly type even just Western European languages like French or Spanish. I’ve never (voluntarily) used the Windows US layout, but this still comes as somewhat of a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

The *phoneme* there is written as /æ/. But you may have gotten confused because the /æ/ in "hand" sounds very different from the /æ/ in "after." This is because of [æ-tensing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising), which alters the phonetic realization of /æ/ before nasal consonants in American English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).